# How to import deleteUser firebase sdk ./src/layouts/ExtraOptionLayout.js Attempted import error: 'deleteUser' is not exported from 'firebase/auth'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Just trying to import this clientside in JS to simply allow a user to delete their account.

Very simple, not sure what the problem is.

```
Attempted import error: 'deleteUser' is not exported from 'firebase/auth'.
```

Comment: How did you import `deleteUser`? Could you please include a reproducible code in your question.

Comment: I was doing `import { deleteUser } from 'firebase/auth', but I've since solved my use case by using `const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;` and using `user.delete().then(function() {
        console.log("deleted")
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      }) `

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to keep things simple for clientside is just:

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
user.delete().then(function() {
    console.log("deleted")})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error)      
})
```